# node js express Whil using app.param 4 url get request doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express, router

I am using app.param to enter a parameter into the url which is the user username and it works except that any get requests right after that do not load the html page for the client.  I am not getting any type of error except after the page fails to load i get a 404 error on the page.  What could be the issue, i even tried router.param instead and got the same result. obviously the functionallity requires this to work on multiple pages.

```
//Profile views for other users

app.param('username', function(req, res, next, username) {

    User.findOne({ 'local.username' : username }, function(err, user) {

        if(err)
            throw err;

        if(user==null) 
            return false;

        req.person = user;

    next();

    });

});

app.get('/:username', function(req, res) {

    Profile.findOne({ 'pic.username' : req.person.local.username }, function(err, profilepic) {

        if(err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(profilepic);

        res.render('pages/visitprofile', {
        user : req.person,
        profilepic : profilepic

    });
    });

});

app.get('/photos/:username', function(req, res) {

    Profile.findOne({ 'pic.username' : req.person.local.username }, function(err, profilepic) {

        if(err)
            throw err;

        res.render('pages/photos', {
            profilepic : profilepic
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('express is listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: Could you add the URL you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `app.get('/:username', callback)` syntax, you need to look for `req.params.username`.

```
app.get('/photos/:username', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.params.username);
}
```

Comment: I got it working but now none of the static files (images) are being loaded for the two last get requests